# 2012 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Well, Mi Yodeya's very first [moderator election](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to an end. Our winners are:

[image: msh210] [image: Double AA] [image: Monica Cello]

Please give them a warm welcome, and hearty thanks and congratulations for volunteering!

Also, a sincere thank you to the rest of our [Moderators Pro Tempore](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176/moderator-pro-tem-announcement), who (along with msh210) helped shepherd the site through its beta:

[image: Isaac Moses]
[image: WAF]
[image: HodofHod]

Comment: Mazel Tov, everyone!

Comment: Wait, is Isaac no longer a mod? I assumed he'd retain his status as the founder.

Comment: I suspect he'd have been a shoo-in if he had run. But, he opted not to. Frankly, I don't blame him if he wants to just enjoy *using* the site for a bit - he's certainly paid his dues! (Ref: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5391647#5391647) @Seth

Comment: @shog9, thanks. I missed that. I figured Isaac was exempt and would retain mod privileges. If he'd run I would certainly have voted for him, but I think he knows that virtually everyone would have.

Comment: Mazel Tov and best wishes for the future!

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone is wondering, this is the election output (assuming I'm reading the file properly). For more information about the method used see [How are moderator election votes counted, in plain English?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77541/166155)

```
Loading ballots from file judaism-stackexchange-com-2012-election-results.blt.
Ballot file contains 6 candidates and 68 ballots.
No candidates have withdrawn.
Ballot file contains 68 non-empty ballots.

Counting votes for Mi Yodeya Moderator Election 2012 using Meek STV.
6 candidates running for 3 seats.

 R|msh210   |HodofHod |Double AA|Monica Ce|Seth J   |Adam Mosh|Exhausted|Surplus  |Threshold
  |         |         |         |llio     |         |eh       |         |         |         
============================================================================================
 1|24.000000| 7.000000|15.000000|15.000000| 5.000000| 2.000000| 0.000000| 6.999999|17.000001
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count of first choices. Candidate msh210 has reached the threshold and is elected.
============================================================================================
 2|17.000016| 9.333328|17.333328|15.291666| 6.458330| 2.291666| 0.291666| 0.479176|16.927084
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: msh210, 0.708334. Candidate Double AA has reached the threshold and is
  | elected.
============================================================================================
 3|18.416684|12.499992|21.208326|15.583332|         |         | 0.291666| 5.770842|16.927084
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Seth J and Adam Mosheh and transferring votes. All losing
  | candidates are eliminated.
============================================================================================
 4|18.109901|14.427072|17.430079|16.585282|         |         | 1.447666| 2.263812|16.638084
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: msh210, 0.651042 and Double AA, 0.798134.
============================================================================================
 5|16.833307|15.398094|17.081528|16.900919|         |         | 1.786152| 1.155365|16.553463
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: msh210, 0.598131 and Double AA, 0.761869. Candidate Monica Cellio has reached
  | the threshold and is elected.

Winners are msh210, Double AA, and Monica Cellio.
```

Comment: How'd you get this? Did you run OpenSTV yourself?

Comment: @IsaacMoses Yes.

Comment: Open question: how do we feel about having received "68 non-empty ballots"?